# Iterating over files in a directory and applying a user defined function automatically

Tags: python

I have over 40 excel sheets hat I needed to transpose , removed missing variables etc. I wrote two functions that performed all of the above task. 
However I manually entered the first file, how can I iterate over the files and apply this function to all the files in my directory?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Thanks I figured it out